# How to show progress bar in adobe air app?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, air, progress-bar, jquery-ui-progressbar

I'm trying to show a progress bar in adobe air app, but having problems. I'm using jquery ui progress bar, but the progress bar isn't being shown and I don't know why. I'm trying the simple example shown in the jquery demo site,

1. create a div with id progressbar,
2. using this command  `$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: 59 });`

I would assume the progress bar should would show up but I get nothing. Any help?

Just to show some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>      
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var count = 50;
    startProgress();
    function startProgress() 
    {
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: count
        }); 
    }                       
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div> 
    <div id="progressbar" ></div>

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess it's assumed that you need to include both jquery UI and jquery scripts?

Comment: Yes I included jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js and jquery1.6 scripts.

Comment: @user814628 FYI, put 4 spaces before your code to format it correctly.  See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more formatting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your script in a ready handler.  This will cause the script to execute after the DOM is ready, instead of immediately (before the `progressbar` div exists in the DOM.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 50;

    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: count
    }); 
});
```

Note that I removed the `startProgress()` function declaration, as its unnecessary.

Comment: Figured it out. Looks like I had to add jqueri-ui.css for it to show